# US Federal IT: If the deductions proposed to be eliminated are eliminated, will the AMT be a toothless tiger?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction

The House and Senate tax reform bills between them propose to eliminate deductibility of state and local taxes and cap mortgage deductions for mortgages greater than 500K, plus eliminate the Medical Deduction. The  bills also propose to eliminate the Alternate Minimum Tax. But does not eliminating all those deductions go a long way to eliminating the AMT anyway ?   If the AMT were kept, and the deductions I mentioned abolished, who would still be affected by AMT and for what?

Comment: There are some bigger tax preference items that would still make the AMT meaningful.